# Python mock patch sample code doesn't work

Tags: python-unittest.mock

I was following a short example online for mock.patch(), why I am getting the following errors:

---

> machine-1:~/MOCK$ ***python tests.py***

...

> File "~/MOCK/tests.py", line
> 21, in test_call_api self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'

---

### my_module.py

```
import requests

def call_api(data):
    response = requests.post("http://mi6.uk/agents/", data=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Everything is good")
    return response.json()
```

### tests.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main, mock
from my_module import call_api

class MyModuleTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("my_module.requests.post")             
    def test_call_api(self, mock_request_post):                 
        mock_res = mock.Mock(status_code=200)  
        mock_res.json.return_value = {         
            "result": [
                {
                    "name": "John Doe"
                }
            ]
        }

        mock_request_post.return_value = mock_res  

        resp = call_api(data={"state": False})
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It seems you're constructing a JSON response that only has one attribute `result`. Where do you expect `status_code` to come from? Also, post the link to the tutorial you claim to be following.

Comment: @Ahhijit Sarkar:
Link: https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/mocking-around-with-python-and-unittest/

I changed the variable names and simplify the codes a bit, but it's the first example in the linked article that I am using.